# Svelte store, calculate total value of items in array of objects

Tags: frontend, svelte, sveltekit

I am creating a custom `Svelte` store to use it as a shopping cart. I want to store `CartItem[]` inside. I am trying to calculate the total `price*quantity` for all items in the store. However `cart.total()` returns `undefined`.

```js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

export interface CartItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}

function cartStore() {
    const {subscribe, set, update} = writable<CartItem[]>([]);

    return {
        subscribe,
        add: (item: CartItem) => update((items) => [...items, item]),
        remove: (id: number) => update((items) => items.filter((item) => item.id !== id)),
        clear: () => set([]),
        get total() {
            return subscribe((items) => items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0));
        }
    };
}

export const cart = cartStore();
```

Then in my component I do:

```html
<div class="basis-1/2 text-right text-xl font-bold">
      {cart.total()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `total` property in your `cartStore` function is not correctly calculating the *total value* of items in the array. The `subscribe` function is asynchronous and returns a function to unsubscribe, not the value of the items. Therefore, you cannot directly use `subscribe` to calculate the total value.

Instead, you should use the `get` function from `svelte/store` to retrieve the current value of the store. This function creates a temporary subscription, reads the value, and then unsubscribes. It's not recommended for hot code paths, but it's suitable for this use case.

I will modify your `total` to this:

```js
import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';

function cartStore() {
   const {subscribe, set, update} = writable<CartItem[]>([]);

   return {
       subscribe,
       add: (item: CartItem) => update((items) => [...items, item]),
       remove: (id: number) => update((items) => items.filter((item) => item.id !== id)),
       clear: () => set([]),
       get total() {
           const items = get(this);
           return items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
       }
   };
}

export const cart = cartStore();
```

- `get(this)` - used to retrieve the current value of the cart store.
- `reduce` - used to calculate the total value of all items in the cart. This approach is more in line with the recommended usage of Svelte stores svelte.dev.

This approach is not reactive, so if you want to keep track of the *total value* reactively, you should subscribe to the store and update the total value whenever the store changes. This could be done in a Svelte component using the `$cart` syntax to access the store value reactively.

To display the total price in your Svelte component, you can use the `$` prefix to access the value of the store:

```html
<div class="basis-1/2 text-right text-xl font-bold">
   {$cart.total}
</div>
```

This will automatically update the displayed value whenever items are added to or removed from the cart

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer and it solves my problem. However I have a minor comment. I cannot use `{$cart.total}` because in this context `$cart` returns the value of the store which is `CartItem[]` and this object has no method `total` since the method belongs to the store and not the value. What I did was to create `$: cartTotal = cart.total` and use it instead. However, this is still not reactive. When I change the variable in the code and there is a hot reload the value gets updated, but when using `cart.add()` `cartTotal` is not updated. Even when the store value changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is where derived values or a [derived store](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#derived) come in:

Derived value example:
( This only works inside *.svelte file, and that limits its reuse )

```js
$: total = $cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
```

Derived store example:

```js
const items = writable<CartItem[]>([]);
const combined = derived(items, $items => {
  return {
    items: $items,
    total: $items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0)
   };
});
```

This example creates a new store and combined the items and the total into an object. But you could also create a derived store that just returns the total:

```js
const total = derived(cart, $items => $items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
```

A derived store is also a store, and when the source(s) of a derived store change, value of the derived store is recalculated.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/742ada64d86041728573c80e5ab72107?version=4.2.2)